# Does the Axiom of Choice give the strategy function for the existential quantifier in all formulas?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I was digging around the Axiom of Choice and looking at it from the angle that without choice, $\forall _{x\in S} \exists_{y\in\cup S} y\in x$ doesn't give us a function from the $x$ to the $y$, I found it obvious again and the situation without choice now looks ridiculous. Surely if the existential quantifier has a strategy, it should also exist in the object world of set theory.

I'm pretty sure choice can prove the existence of such a strategy for any claim of the form $\forall_{x\in X} \exists_{y\in Y} P(x,y)$ (in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275142/the-axiom-of-choice-as-a-consequence-of-a-stronger-semantics?rq=1) J.D. Hamkins seems to say that the bounds on $y$ can be dropped, but I don't understand why).
Now I am worried that the "ridiculous" situation arises even with choice in the case of more complicated forms. My intuition is that any true formula with bounded quantifiers in prenex form should imply the existence of a function describing the winning strategy for the existential quantifier. As far as I can tell, this even makes sense as an axiom schema of set theory. Has such an axiom schema been considered? Is it implied by $AC$?   Is it at all (eqi)consistent with $ZF$?

Comment: The "$\forall\exists$" case is already as bad as it gets: the axiom of choice in fact gives us "strategies" for all first-order formulas with bounded quantifiers. (Think about how **Skolemization** lets us shift everything to a "higher-order $\exists\forall$-form.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber I know this procedure is analogous to Skolemization, I haven't heard of the "higher-order ∃∀-form" but I guess you mean something like "there exists a strategy for the ∃ such that for all strategies for ∀, ∃ wins", with the strategy for ∃ being the function that Skolemization adds to the theory. So I guess you mean that we can translate any formula to the "∀∃" form  with the quantifiers being over strategies? It's not obvious to me how to do this. It still fills like if we wanted to try then it the strategy for ∃ should come first, but then AC doesn't even seem to help...

Comment: ok I think I got it now, the strategy can be constructed iteratively from the left to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the construction of the strategy function generalizes to longer formulas. For completeness, for a formula $\forall_{x\in X}\exists_{y\in Y} R(x,y)$ where $R$ is a formula with two free variables, take the function $f:X\to 2^Y$ with $ f(x) =\{y \in Y : R(x,y)\}$ and compose it with a choice function for $2^Y$. This gives us $\exists_{g : X \to Y}\forall_{x\in X} R(x,g(x))$.

For a longer formula we can move the existential quantifiers to the left one by one. For example for
$$\forall_{a\in A}\exists_{b\in B}\forall_{c\in C}\exists_{d\in D} S(a,b,c,d)$$
we can first take $$\forall_{a\in A}\exists_{b\in B} (\forall_{c\in C}\exists_{d\in D} S(a,b,c,d))$$ with the part in the parentheses being the $R$ from the two quantifier construction. We obtain $$\exists_{g : A \to B}\forall_{a\in A} \forall_{c\in C}\exists_{d\in D} S(a,b,c,d)$$ which can be rewritten as

$$\exists_{g : A \to B}\forall_{(a,c)\in A\times C}\exists_{d\in D} S(a,g(a),c,d)$$

then we can apply the construction again the part after the first existential quantifier.

Comment: This answer is very lucid. (+1) But I don't know why $ \exists b \in B$ is written twice in the second equation.

Comment: @Hermis14 corrected, thanks for the catch